# not able to read back protobuff from file

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers

i am writing a `protobuf` into file and then reading again as follows

protobuff block

```
Person personOne =
                  Person.newBuilder()
                    .setId(1234)
                    .setName("John Doe")
                    .setEmail("jdoe@example.com")
                    .addPhone(
                      Person.PhoneNumber.newBuilder()
                        .setNumber("555-4321")
                        .setType(Person.PhoneType.HOME))
                    .build();
```

writing to file , here `data` is `byte[]`  and parameter is `personOne.toByteArray()`

```
        try {
             FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
             output.write(data);
             output.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

reading from file , but while reading i am getting error

```
          try {

             FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
             byte [] buffer = new byte[input.read()];

             input.read(buffer);
             input.close();
             return buffer;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

error

```
    03-20 21:04:39.060: W/System.err(18074): com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
    03-20 21:04:39.090: W/System.err(18074):    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:498)
    03-20 21:04:39.110: W/System.err(18074):    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessage.java:193)
    03-20 21:04:39.110: W/System.err(18074):    at com.example.protodemo.AddressBookProtos$Person.<init>(AddressBookProtos.java:124)
    03-20 21:04:39.110: W/System.err(18074):    at com.example.protodemo.AddressBookProtos$Person.<init>(AddressBookProtos.java:107)
    03-20 21:04:39.110: W/System.err(18074):    at com.example.protodemo.AddressBookProtos$Person$1.parsePartialFrom(AddressBookProtos.java:186)
    03-20 21:04:39.110: W/System.err(18074):    at com.example.protodemo.AddressBookProtos$Person$1.parsePartialFrom(AddressBookProtos.java:1)
    03-20 21:04:39.110: W/System.err(18074):    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:141)
    03-20 21:04:39.110: W/System.err(18074):    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:176)
    03-20 21:04:39.110: W/System.err(18074):    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:188)
    03-20 21:04:39.110: W/System.err(18074):    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:193)
    03-20 21:04:39.110: W/System.err(18074):    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
    03-20 21:04:39.120: W/System.err(18074):    at com.example.protodemo.AddressBookProtos$Person.parseFrom(AddressBookProtos.java:1088)
    03-20 21:04:39.120: W/System.err(18074):    at com.example.protodemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
    03-20 21:04:39.120: W/System.err(18074):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
    03-20 21:04:39.120: W/System.err(18074):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
    03-20 21:04:39.120: W/System.err(18074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
    03-20 21:04:39.120: W/System.err(18074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
    03-20 21:04:39.120: W/System.err(18074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
    03-20 21:04:39.120: W/System.err(18074):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
    03-20 21:04:39.120: W/System.err(18074):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    03-20 21:04:39.120: W/System.err(18074):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    03-20 21:04:39.120: W/System.err(18074):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
    03-20 21:04:39.120: W/System.err(18074):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    03-20 21:04:39.120: W/System.err(18074):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    03-20 21:04:39.130: W/System.err(18074):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
    03-20 21:04:39.130: W/System.err(18074):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
    03-20 21:04:39.130: W/System.err(18074):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Update**
previously i was storing data into `data.txt` file but now i have removed the exception and getting new error

```
03-20 21:25:58.920: W/System.err(18470): com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
03-20 21:25:58.920: W/System.err(18470):    at com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder.mergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet.java:498)
03-20 21:25:58.920: W/System.err(18470):    at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.parseUnknownField(GeneratedMessage.java:193)
03-20 21:25:58.920: W/System.err(18470):    at com.example.protodemo.AddressBookProtos$Person.<init>(AddressBookProtos.java:124)
03-20 21:25:58.920: W/System.err(18470):    at com.example.protodemo.AddressBookProtos$Person.<init>(AddressBookProtos.java:107)
03-20 21:25:58.930: W/System.err(18470):    at com.example.protodemo.AddressBookProtos$Person$1.parsePartialFrom(AddressBookProtos.java:186)
03-20 21:25:58.930: W/System.err(18470):    at com.example.protodemo.AddressBookProtos$Person$1.parsePartialFrom(AddressBookProtos.java:1)
03-20 21:25:58.930: W/System.err(18470):    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:141)
03-20 21:25:58.930: W/System.err(18470):    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:176)
03-20 21:25:58.930: W/System.err(18470):    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:188)
03-20 21:25:58.930: W/System.err(18470):    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:193)
03-20 21:25:58.930: W/System.err(18470):    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
03-20 21:25:58.930: W/System.err(18470):    at com.example.protodemo.AddressBookProtos$Person.parseFrom(AddressBookProtos.java:1088)
03-20 21:25:58.930: W/System.err(18470):    at com.example.protodemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
03-20 21:25:58.930: W/System.err(18470):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
03-20 21:25:58.930: W/System.err(18470):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
03-20 21:25:58.930: W/System.err(18470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
03-20 21:25:58.930: W/System.err(18470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
03-20 21:25:58.940: W/System.err(18470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
03-20 21:25:58.940: W/System.err(18470):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
03-20 21:25:58.940: W/System.err(18470):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 21:25:58.940: W/System.err(18470):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 21:25:58.940: W/System.err(18470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
03-20 21:25:58.940: W/System.err(18470):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 21:25:58.940: W/System.err(18470):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-20 21:25:58.940: W/System.err(18470):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
03-20 21:25:58.940: W/System.err(18470):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
03-20 21:25:58.940: W/System.err(18470):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: i am using android and its using `java.io.File`

Comment: And Dalvik is still not doing Java 7? That sounds fishy

Comment: i am using JRE7 only , i just saw in eclipse

Comment: i my project `Files - > android.provider.MediaStore`

Comment: i am using file name as `data.txt` then i tried to pass only file name without extension , now i am getting different error

Comment: @fge: Files is not in android. Your comments are irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

From your code:

```
byte [] buffer = new byte[input.read()];
```

Here you appear to be reading the first byte of the input and using it as the size of the buffer.  However, when you wrote the file, you didn't actually write a size in the first byte; you only wrote the data:

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
output.write(data);
output.close();
```

Instead of reading the file content to a `byte[]`, just pass the input stream itself to `parseFrom`, like:

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
Person person = Person.parseFrom(input);
```

If you must read into a byte array, then allocate the array according to the actual size of the file, e.g. using `File#length()`.  Or, actually write the message size before writing the message.  (Don't write it as just a single byte, though, because then you'll have problems if your message is larger than 255 bytes.)